# Oauth 2.0 Authentication custom login page in Spring Boot

Tags: oauth-2.0

Here is my Problem statement:
I want to do OAuth authentication with external Authorization Server(say External Identity Provider) But user should provide credentials on my custom login page. I know when we do Oauth user must be redirected to Identity provider to authenticate and complete OAuth dance. But in my case, I want user to provide credentials on my login screen. No where in the process, user should see the identity provider login page. Any thoughts?

Comment: i wonder, why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @OhadR I realized that my use case will not fit grant type authorization code. Later, I read your comment carefully and you were absolutely correct that my use case fits in Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type. Now using Spring boot I am able to achieve that. I am new to OAuth and somehow, I was misled to use authorization code and I didn't bother to take a look at other grant type. But thanks to guide me in the right direction. Cheers!

Comment: you are welcome! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user enters his credentials on your login page, how will your app verify these creds with the identity server?

The idea of oAuth is that you app (the client app) will not be exposed to the user's creds.

Note: If there is a tight relationship between the client app and the identity-provider (e.g. Facebook and the Facebook app for mobile) so you can perform this with [Resource Owner Password Credentials grant type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3).

Comment: If the user enters his credentials on your login page, how will your app verify these creds with the identity server? - Identity server exposes rest API to do authentication by providing username and password and if it is success then a sessionToken is returned which can be passed to userAuthorizationUri to bypass the identity server login page.<br/> I agree that in oauth, credentials are not exposed but as I said before this is our requirement. I am able to achieve it though. Please find below my answer. Thanks for your comment